# How to convert variable to struct member in IDA?

Tags: ida, windows, pe

I'm working on a windows program which is walking PEB Ldr list. the related types are as follows:

```
struct LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY {
    LIST_ENTRY InLoadOrderLinks;         // offset = 0, size = 0x10
    LIST_ENTRY InMemoryOrderLinks;   // offset = 0x10, size = 0x10
    // ...
    UNICODE_STRING FullDllName;       // offset = 0x48, size = 0x10
    UNICODE_STRING BaseDllName;     // offset = 0x58, size = 0x10
};
```

the pseudocode IDA generated is like that:

```
i = (LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY *)NtCurrentPeb()->Ldr->InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink;
CurDllName = i->FullDllName.Buffer;     // FullDllName should be BaseDllName!
CurDllNameLength = i->FullDllName.Length;
```

The problem is, `i->FullDllName` should be `i->BaseDllName`, because `i` is not `LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY *` but actually `LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY * + 0x10` (address of `LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY.InMemoryOrderLinks`).

The correct output should be like that:

```
i = NtCurrentPeb()->Ldr->InMemoryOrderModuleList.Flink;
LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY *Node = CONTAINING_RECORD(i, LDR_DATA_TABLE_ENTRY, InMemoryOrderLinks);
CurDllName = Node->BaseDllName.Buffer;
CurDllNameLength = Node->BaseDllName.Length;
```

In case `i` is an offset, Is there any way I can do to change type of `i` to something correct (like struct members) or just add the variable `Node` in IDA? The `Node` pointer I wrote here seems to be optimized out.

I tried `CONTAINING_RECORD` but it seems not applicable here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right-click `i` and select either:

- `Create new struct type` to create a new type deducted from **function-scoped** access to the variable
- `Convert to struct *` to apply an existing type

You can inspect and manage structure types in `Local Types` tab (`View/Open subviews/Local Types`), including the types you already have (found in system APIs and debug symbols).